# Can I use excel to calculate my gpa by using a switch statement?

Tags: excel

I am just trying to make a quick gpa calculator file in excel.  I am thinking I could just have the class names in rows, then along the columns I can have "Grade" and "Credits".  I am wondering if it would be possible to make a switch statement or use a dictionary to calculate how much each grade would be e.g. "A" = 4.0, "A-" = "3.7" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function.

```
     A    B    C  D
1    A   4.0   A- =VLOOKUP(C1;A1:B99;2;TRUE)
2    A-  3.7   A  =VLOOKUP(C2;A1:B99;2;TRUE)
```

Comment: hlookup would be fine too, but vlookup makes it look better